# Does rolling back edits on a flagged post change the flag state to disputed?

Tags: support, edits, flags, declined-flags, rollbacks

I saw a post with title of something like:

> "case closed, case closed, case closed"

and question body of "case closed. no one can help me", so I flagged it as spam. later I saw that my flag has been declined and the question is totally different. I checked the question again and I saw that there has been an edit to question (that changed it to spam) and after I had flagged it someone had it rolled back to a previous edit (that makes my flag invalid).

Roll backing an edit should change the flag state to disputed right?

Comment: Vandalism should  be rolled back, not flagged.

Comment: well edit was by the user itself and I didn't know the question was edited.

Comment: Please _do not_ use the spam flag for anything that's not _outright advertising_. Vandalism isn't spam.

Comment: well, you should _definitely_ check if there's an [edited] card.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy or religion or job or...

Comment: If it's been edited in the 5 minute window though, that's a different story.

Comment: Your flag was probably declined before the post was rolled back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, rollback reset any spam/offensive flags that were cast between the time of the revision being rolled back to and the time of rollback, as described in [the faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work):

> **Rolling back a post to a previous state will revert to the number of flags from that particular revision**. This allows the OP (or someone else with edit rights) to rollback a post to which someone else introduced spam or offensive content in a later revision. However, as a general user, once you mark a post as spam or offensive, you cannot take it back.

Note your flag was not *declined* but rather *disputed* which has no negative effect whatsoever.

Comment: In this case, a moderator explicitly declined the spam flag, because the post wasn't actually spam. Another user had taken care of the defacing edit in the meantime. I don't think that paragraph in the FAQ is actually correct, since I swear I've seen spam flags that lasted through rollbacks.

Comment: That's interesting, @Brad! Question is, how can we be sure enough so we can change the faq and ask to change the rollback tooltip?

Comment: nope my flag has been declined. so I have flagged right after rollback (i think I have opened the page the rollback has happened and I just flagged new one while I wasn't seeing the change) this is the link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912462/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread-skipped-96-fr)